# How exactly serialization works in C++?

Tags: c++, serialization, file-io

Here are my code files:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Car.h"
#include "Engine.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
   Car* car = new Car(1984);
   /* do something here */
   delete car;   
   return 0;
}
```

Car.h

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Engine.h"

class Car {
public:
   Car(int);
   virtual ~Car();
   void serialize(ostream& s) {
      engine.serialize(s);
      s << ' ' << yearModel;
   } 
   void unserialize(istream& s) {
      engine.unserialize(s);
      s >> yearModel;
   }
private:
   Engine engine;
   int yearModel;
};

#endif /* CAR_H */
```

Car.cpp

```
#include "Car.h"

Car::Car(int year) {
   yearModel = year;
}

Car::~Car() {
}
```

Engine.h

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Engine {
public:
   Engine();
   virtual ~Engine();
   void serialize(ostream& s) {
      s << ' ' << engineType;
   } 
   void unserialize(istream& s) {
      s >> engineType;
   }
private:
   int engineType;
};

#endif /* ENGINE_H */
```

Engine.cpp

```
#include "Engine.h"

Engine::Engine() {
   engineType = 1;
}

Engine::~Engine() {
}
```

What I want to do in the main.cpp is to save the created Car object to file.txt and later read it from there. How does that exactly work? For example: how do I call the serialization function in Car class?

I'm sorry if I sound like a noob, but this whole serialization thing is pretty new to me.

Edit: Code compiles now when I added 'void' in front of all serialize- and unserialize-functions.

Comment: BTW, you might consider serializing in textual format (e.g. in [JSON](http://json.org/) perhaps using [jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/), etc...) and you could also consider [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) or [s11n](http://s11n.net/s11n/) etc...

Comment: Note: `Car* car = new Car(1984); /* do something here */ delete car; return 0;` Former Java programmer? Why not simply `Car car(1984); /* do something here */ return 0;` (See http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#4 (use the arrow keys or PgUp/PgDn to navigate))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with serialization: a function needs a return type, even if it is `void`. So this is wrong:

```
serialize(ostream& s) // look, no return type.
```

You probably need to either return `void`,

```
void serialize(ostream& s) { /* code as before */ }
```

or return the stream by reference to allow for chaining:

```
ostream& serialize(ostream& s) {
  return s << ' ' << engineType;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding void-type in front of the functions fixed the problem.